# Rear wheel with wheel nut very hard to unscrew

Tags: wheels, rear-wheel

but I'm new to biking and repairs itself.

I have a bike that has a wheel nut for its real wheel and I need to change the tire because of a flat.
However, turning the nut didn't work, as in the nut was almost as if it was bolted onto it.

I am currently using an adjustable wrench (one with the scrolling screw in the middle), and I have a lot of trouble getting it to turn even the slightest.

Heard a regular rigid 15mm wrench might work, but I am not exactly sure.

Any ideas on how to unscrew it and change the flat?

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like your bike rear axle has a bolt-on axle, with a pair of 15mm hex nuts holding it in place.

The best tool for the job is either a 15mm ring spanner or a 15mm 6 sided socket.   When I had an alfine gearbox I kept a light 15mm ringspanner in the bike's toolkit and its better AND lighter than an adjustable.

An adjustable spanner tends to have a little flex and will round-over the flats on the nut if its too tight.

[image]

For added lightness you can even cut off the open-end and just carry the ring part and the handle.

Comment: Ah ok, yea the adjustable one did have a bunch of flex and really messed up my hand. Thanks for your answer! I will get one right now off of amazon. :D